# I have problem with image folder directory on live server using laravel

Tags: laravel

I have uploaded my laravel project on the live server and I have uploaded public all files inside the public_html and other all laravel file uploaded outside the public_html but the problem is that I am trying to upload image in this directory **public_html/uploads/images** but not uploading and the image is uploading in this directory **yourstitchart_web/public/public_html/uploads/images**

Note:- image should be uploaded inside in this directory  **/public_html/uploads/images**

Does anyone have an idea please help me thanks.

[image: cpanel folder directory]

**file system.php**

```
       'yourstitchart' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('public_html/uploads/images'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads/images',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to use the public_path() helper - this returns the base public directory.

Try

```
 'yourstitchart' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '/uploads/images',
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads/images',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: I have used this root path but unfortunately, It's not working please help me please check https://ibb.co/Fwb6Rzm

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem and this was work for me.
If you use public_path() to get the root directory and your Public folder placed on public_html then you need to do this.

---

find -> app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

---

then use this code

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
      return '/home/yourCpanelDirectoryName/public_html';
    });
}
```

if it's not work, then you can try it

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
      return base_path().'/public_html';
    });
}
```